# convert json format data to dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have this data dictionary:

```py
data = {'timestamp': 1555063200000, 'exchange': 'NSE_FO', 'symbol': 'NIFTY19APR11600CE', 'ltp': 152.75, 'close': 151.4}
```

Can any please guide me to convert the dictionary above to a dataframe in python?

Trying to run the following line:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(data)
```

is throwing an error:

```py
 print(pd.DataFrame().from_dict(data, orient='columns'))
  File "C:\Users\balveer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1138, in from_dict
    return cls(data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\balveer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 392, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\balveer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 212, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with that line it should work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])
```

your error comes from the scalar values in data, it should be lists or you have to specify an index in the DataFrame method.

I hope it helps you

Adrien

Answer (score 0):

I think this is you need to first build your dataframe and noting what are your columns, then insert your data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = data.keys())
df.loc[0] = data.values()
```

Comment: timestamp                                           exchange                                             symbol                                                ltp                                              close
0  (1555063200000, NSE_FO, NIFTY19APR11600CE, 152...  (1555063200000, NSE_FO, NIFTY19APR11600CE, 152...  (1555063200000, NSE_FO, NIFTY19APR11600CE, 152...  (1555063200000, NSE_FO, NIFTY19APR11600CE, 152...  (1555063200000, NSE_FO, NIFTY19APR11600CE, 152...

Process finished with exit code 0...Not getting correct output, row is going to every column

Comment: Works good on my part, output received is:
```close      timestamp             symbol     ltp exchange
0  151.4  1555063200000  NIFTY19APR11600CE  152.75   NSE_FO```